# Ubuntu Impress image

Tags: libreoffice

My Impress program used to have an image percentage control down in the lower right corner of the window.  How do I get that back using Ubuntu 20.4.6lts

Comment: does [this reference](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-can-one-scale-an-image-by-a-percentage-in-impress/49384) help?